# Ciclo while me da un numero más al requerido

Tags: c

Estoy haciendo el algoritmo de Luhn en C, hice está función que en base a los números que ingresen sacará los números de posiciones pares iniciando por el penúltimo. El problema es que me da el último numero 2 veces (por ejemplo, de `4003600000000014` me da 2 veces `4`). No se a qué se deba; tengo la noción de que es por la condición, pero no puedo resolverlo

```
    long multiplos(long card)
    {
        int mult;
        // secuencia que saca los numero en locaciones pares de la tarjeta
        while (card > 0)
        {
        int mod = card % 100;
        card = card / 100;
        int m2 = mod / 10;
        // multiplica los numero pares por 2
        mult = m2 * 2;
        printf("%i", mult);
        printf("\n");
        }
        return mult;
    }
```

Comment: Puedes mostrar como lo ejecutas?

Answer (score -2):

La función multiplos() que has escrito parece estar diseñada para sacar los números de posiciones pares iniciando por el penúltimo de un número dado. Sin embargo, tu implementación tiene algunos errores que pueden causar comportamientos inesperados.

Uno de los errores es que estás imprimiendo el resultado de la multiplicación en cada iteración del bucle while, lo que puede causar que el mismo número se imprima varias veces. Además, el resultado de la función siempre será el último valor que se asigne a la variable mult antes de que termine el bucle, lo que puede causar que la función no devuelva el resultado esperado.

Para solucionar estos problemas, puedes modificar la función de la siguiente manera:

En lugar de imprimir el resultado de la multiplicación en cada iteración del bucle while, puedes almacenar los resultados en una lista y luego imprimir la lista completa una vez que el bucle termine.
En lugar de devolver el último valor de la variable mult, puedes devolver la lista completa de resultados como resultado de la función.
Aquí tienes una implementación de la función multiplos() que corrige estos problemas:

```
long multiplos(long card)
{
    int mult;
    int mult_list[10]; // lista para almacenar los resultados
    int index = 0;     // índice para la lista

    // secuencia que saca los numero en locaciones pares de la tarjeta
    while (card > 0)
    {
        int mod = card % 100;
        card = card / 100;
        int m2 = mod / 10;
        // multiplica los numero pares por 2
        mult = m2 * 2;

        // almacenamos el resultado en la lista
        mult_list[index] = mult;
        index++;
    }

    // imprimimos la lista de resultados
    printf("Lista de resultados: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
    {
        printf("%i ", mult_list[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    // devolvemos la lista de resultados como resultado de la función
    return mult_list;
}
```

Comment: Y esto como contestas porque se esta imprimiendo dos veces el 4?

Comment: Usar chatGPT está prohibido en [es.so], además, usar chatGPT sin citar la fuente es considerado [Plagio](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagio). Relacionado: [cheatGPT (chatGPT) nos ha alcanzado en SOes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5450/cheatgpt-chatgpt-nos-ha-alcanzado-en-soes), [Temporary policy: ChatGPT is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned). Tu cuenta puede ser suspendida por este motivo.